# CSV Import SQL float killed to int

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, floating-point, int

i got a problem when importing a csv file to a sql server even with SSIS assist. My csv File has amongst others a product price stored as a float (like 123.45). when i try to import this to a table of mine (or even when it imports the whole csv into a new table) the float gets killed to a int. doesnt mind if i set it to float, double-precision float, decimal with DataScale = 2. In the Preview it shows it perfect, after doing this its stored as int. Doesnt even mind which data type my destination field is (perfect would be money, also tried float but didnt work).

Side question would be if i can import the csv with t-sql into an own table just using some rows, but the float problem is most important.

thx @ all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing your csv into a table where all columns are varchar and then insert from that table into destination table.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Had to adjust one column to import it as text but its good enough, now i´m gonna import it in an own table via t-sql to provide it to the frontend. thanks